# Malicious requests from private network (Kubernetes)

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, hacking, nginx-ingress

Recently I'm having many malicious requests to my nginx-ingress pod but I don't understand how's possible they're from a private network. Some examples:

```
10.114.0.3 - - [11/Oct/2021:09:07:09 +0000] "GET /cgi-bin/.%2e/%2e%2e/%2e%2e/%2e%2e/%2e%2e/%2e%2e/%2e%2e/%2e%2e/%2e%2e/etc/hosts HTTP/1.1" 400 158 "-" "-" 94 0.015 [] [] - - - - bea3d4941bd57413fa52e4ff01437067
10.114.0.3 - - [11/Oct/2021:09:07:09 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xEE\x01\x00\x00\xEA\x03\x03]\xCDw\x0B\xD4\x92$z\x17\xC4z\xC1s\xFF\x1E\x5C\xE1\xC0\xCE\xEB$<Z\xAB\xC5\xC9L\xB5\xF09-u yd\xD1y\x0Fw\x9A\x94\xB1$\xDC\xC6\xD7\xCB\xE2\xFB\x83\xEEQC*\xBA\xC4E\x0F\xF6\xA6\xFC_a\xB9\x15\x00&\xC0/\xC00\xC0+\xC0,\xCC\xA8\xCC\xA9\xC0\x13\xC0\x09\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 158 "-" "-" 0 0.016 [] [] - - - - 0200c3049215e065bc42749fee66654a
10.114.0.3 - - [11/Oct/2021:09:07:09 +0000] "CONNECT leakix.net:443 HTTP/1.1" 400 158 "-" "-" 0 0.017 [] [] - - - - 43ae42d20fa1fa89fcddddd81801b9a2
10.114.0.3 - - [11/Oct/2021:15:32:02 +0000] "POST /cgi-bin/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/bin/sh HTTP/1.1" 400 158 "-" "-" 51 0.042 [] [] - - - - 862e8fe41db26a92f8db8dd194184044
```

I would think one of our droplet is hacked but we don't have any droplet with IP 10.114.0.3, even if we have similar IPs:

- 10.114.0.2
- 10.114.0.5
- 10.114.0.7

any idea?

Comment: Do you see real external IP addresses on the legitimate requests from the Internet?

Answer (score 3):

What you see is an attack using an exploit in Apache 2.4.49 (only this version is affected). You can read more about it here [CVE-2021-41773](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-41773).
**TLDR:** Path traversal allows attacker to remotely execute code, if files are not protected by `require all denied` configuration.

If you are using any Apache servers upgrade those to, at least, version 2.4.50.
Execute this on your Apache server

```text
curl --data "echo;id" 'http://127.0.0.1:80/cgi-bin/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/bin/sh'
```

If that returns anything other than a 403 error, your server may be vulnerable.

---

Assuming you are using DigitalOcean - check your account activity, and your team activity, for actions `droplet.create` and `droplet.destroy` with suspocious IP.

Check your kube scheduler and controller logs for any suspicious activity.

Comment: Correct! I see those actions from IP 127.0.0.1 with user "k8saas infrastructure". It's also about a week we get alert of type "15 Minute Load Average is running high"

Comment: So from IP and username I'd say it's some log of system maintenance but I'd expect to find some documentation about user "k8saas infrastructure", instead I can't find any reference.